# Can you send custom command using Android Enterprise?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I'm here asking another enigmatic question

Do you know if Android Enterprise is able to send custom commands to device?, I mean, commands like *take screenshot*, *push file*, etc.

Currently I'm reading [this official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand), but this does not mention something related with custom commands, it just mentions about to reboot, lock and reset password.

I hope someone has solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Android Management API does not support custom commands such as taking a screenshot - there are the supported commands in the [`issueCommand` docs you linked to](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand), and one can also affect device state by modifying [Policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies) (though that isn't really about sending commands).

If you want to add custom logic *during device or profile setup*, you can do that by building an app implementing your logic, having it in Play, setting it as [`REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#installtype) in Policy, and setting a [`SetupAction`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#setupaction) to launch the app during setup.

---

An Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) provider might support some form of "custom" commands with their own Device Policy Controller (DPC) - consult their docs for this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Android Enterprise doesn't have the API to do commands like you’ve mentioned. And, these are the only commands available right now.

1. Lock the device.
2. Reset the user's password
3. Reboot the device